# Can we make python take variables than strings from raw_input() builtin function?

Tags: python

I want to know if there is anyway I can have python `raw_input()` to procure a variable call for me.

what I understand is that, `raw_input()` takes whatever comments written in it and convert it to string, much like `%r`, it just prints everything in what I understand as a debugging mode string formatted.

but if we attempt to convert something like this:

```
test1 = int(raw_input("Please write some number:>  "))
print test1 * 100
```

and if we input 100, the next line will perform a calculation function on it, something I am very interested to implement but in this way:

***This isn't a false attempt but to give a general idea of what I want***

```
a = "I will like some candies"
b = "I will like some chocolates"
c = "I will rather die but have fried chicken" 
test2 = raw_input("Please write the variable name you want to print"
```

If this was the way python would take the inputs like, we will have `a` printed for example when the input was given as `a` and so on with `b` and `c` etc.

Is there a way in python to get the program to get an input from us in form of a variable than string. Any conversions?

Thank you all for your help in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a global variable, then you can do:

```
test1 = int(raw_input("Please write some number:>  "))
print test1 * 100

a = "I will like some candies"
b = "I will like some chocolates"
c = "I will rather die but have fried chicken"
test2 = raw_input("Please write the variable name you want to print ")
print globals()[test2]
```

If not, you'll have to specify the namespace of your variable.

Answer (score 1):

No, As you said `raw_input` returns a string. If you you want to return a relevant result based on user input, the best way is using a dictionary for mapping your variable names to their values:

```
my_dict = {'a': "I will like some candies"
           'b': "I will like some chocolates"
           'c': "I will rather die but have fried chicken" }

test2 = raw_input("Please write the variable name you want to print"
warning = "Please choose one of the aforementioned choices (a, b, c)"
print my_dict.get(test2,warning)
```